# Spinner tab size

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

I have spinner on my app and I want to make the spaces between each line larger.
I have already tried `android:TextSize:"30sp"` with no luck 
any ideas?

Comment: Double check that you're setting android:textSize and not android:TextSize. Then make sure you're setting the text size in the resource used by getDropDownView() and not the layout used by getView().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Creating Adapter for your Spinner give custom layout instead of predefined one

Create xml named `spinner_row.xml` (Any name of your choice) in `res/layout` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/cust_view"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:layout_height="36dp" 
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
```

Here you can change the color Text size and width ,height and spacing by setitng the margin and padding  of the Elements in the spinner by modifying this `textview`

Use it like this while creating Adapter

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_row,yourlist);
```

The Last task is routine

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope this will help you.

---

second way,

create a style like this withe attributes of your choice, like test size, padding etc And your style should have a parent `parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem"` as shown in the below style

```
<style name="spinnerStyleView"  parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:background"> @drawable/notetvbg</item>
          <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    </style>
```

And apply style to your spinner by using style attribue

```
 style="@style/spinnerStyleView"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm new programmer and I will be tankful if you will send me a style that already have the bigger spacing thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ArrayAdapter to provide items for the spinner, you would've specified a resource file for the drop down view, maybe `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` ?

You could create your own drop down resource and set the height to whatever you want, then pass that to the adapter instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`

Comment: how can I create new drop down resource?

Comment: a new drop down resource is just a layout file, this is google's layout for simple_spinner_drop_down: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml