# How to fix text length in Android Spinner

Tags: android, text, view, spinner

I have spinner who collect data from DB and display on real time. The problem I am facing is that when the length of an item is quite long then the spinner Stretch itself and goes out of the screen/view. What I want is to have a fix length of my spinner and it should not stretch itself. Here is the view of my Spinner:

[image: Realtime View]

And below is the code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"         
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java:

```
Spinner spinnerRub = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables); 

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: Create a custom TextView and set it as a layout resource for adapter or override the spinner item style check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556321/spinner-tab-size/15556815#15556815

Comment: @Pragnani Thanks for the reply. I have tried all these things but the problem remains. When the text length is long my spinner stretches itself out for the screen :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using wrap content for the width , specify the width (say 120dp or..)based on your requirement.